# Docker- Install Java 8 and Tomcat 8 from tar files

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I want to install java 8 and tomcat 8 using docker extracted from tarballs.
I have following folder structure on my host machine.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me, How I can do it?

Comment: Is this a hard requirement? Or is the ultimate goal to just get access to a dockerized Tomcat? you could use a Dockerfile such as:

[`FROM tomcat:8.5-jre8-alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/)

Comment: Yes, it is a hard requirement.  We are not allowed to download java and tomcat every time  when we want to install the software on new instance as there is limited access to download software on client's environment

Comment: The `tomcat:8.5.20-jre8-alpine` image is 113MB. It gives you a kernel, OS, JRE, and Tomcat. This is really about as small as it is possible to make it. If you build an image that _inherits_ from this, and the client _pulls_ this image: it will _only_ download the 113MB layer if it doesn't have it already. So, you only have to send this once; it will remain in cache after that. If the client pulls an update from you: they will only pull the layer which contains your war/ear artefact. This sounds like a perfect situation. Building an image that extracts from tarballs won't improve on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Dockerfile do

```
COPY ./softwares/java8.tar.gz java8.tar.gz
COPY ./softwares/tomcat8.tar.gz tomcat8.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf java8.tar.gz &&
   tar -xzf tomcat8.tar.gz
```

I'm not in front of an example but from memory that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with below :

1) untar it using :  tar -xz

2) use update-alternatives to set it as default  like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536134/install-specific-java-version-for-12-04/536161#536161)